# Regex match everything after first and until 2nd occurrence of a slash

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

Need to match everything after the first / and until the 2nd / or end of string.  Given the following examples:

```
/US
/CA
/DE/Special1
/FR/Special 1/special2
```

Need the following returned:

```
US
CA
DE
FR
```

Was using this in DataStudio which worked:

```
^(.+?)/
```

However the same in BigQuery is just returning null.  After trying dozens of other examples here, decided to ask myself.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `/([^/]+)`.

Comment: Thanks that works in BigQuery.  Any idea why this works in BigQuery but not with online tools like https://regex101.com ?

Comment: BQ uses a particular library to parse regex (https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).  Other sites and languages might use different libraries/implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such simple extraction - consider alternative of using cheaper string functions instead of more expensive regexp functions. See an example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '/US' line UNION ALL
  SELECT '/CA' UNION ALL
  SELECT '/DE/Special1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '/FR/Special 1/special2' 
)
SELECT line, SPLIT(line, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] value 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row line                    value    
1   /US                     US   
2   /CA                     CA   
3   /DE/Special1            DE   
4   /FR/Special 1/special2  FR
```

Comment: Hmm, I was looking for a string function to do this like I normally would in python but couldn’t get them to work.  This looks good though, thank you!  I’ll try it out.

Comment: Upvoted.  Thanks again, I had looked for a string split method but didn't find one, so am happy to see it exists.  Much better than regex.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches any 1 or more chars as few as possible at the start of a string (up to the first slash) and puts this value in Group 1. Then it consumes a `/` char. It does not actually match what you need.

You can use a regex in BigQuery that matches a string partially and capture the part you need to get as a result:

```
/([^/]+)
```

It will match the first occurrence of a slash followed with one or more chars other than a slash placing the captured substring in the result you get.